# Add column to assign 1, 2, 3 etc based on how many rows contain another value

Tags: r

I feel like this should be a simple thing to do in R but just can't work it out. I've tried googling but haven't been able to find the answer. Hopefully the repex makes it clearer what I am trying to do.

I have large dataframes containing a day number column. I'd like to add another column which counts up until the day number changes.

```
day <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4)

value <- c(32, 43, 54, 23, 76, 88, 11, 23)

df <- data.frame(day, value)
```

So I'd like to add another column which assigns "a" for the first row of day=1 and "b" for the second row of day=1 and then switch back to "a" for first row of day=2.

```
occurrence <- c("a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b")

df2 <- data.frame(day, value, occurrence)
```

So the final dataframe would look like df2

Tried googling and some if_else based code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(day) %>%  
  mutate(occurence = letters[row_number()])

# A tibble: 8 × 3
    day value occurrence
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     
1     1    32 a         
2     1    43 b         
3     2    54 a         
4     3    23 a         
5     3    76 b         
6     3    88 c         
7     4    11 a         
8     4    23 b
```